# Embeding VLC plugin on web site to play RTSP stream

Tags: internet-explorer, stream, vlc, rtsp

I need to open rtsp stream. I have the following code for Firefox and Chrome:

```
<embed 
width="300" 
height="300" 
wmode="transparent" 
id="vlc_1" 
pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
autoplay="true" 
src="rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@MY_IP:MY_PORT/PSIA/streaming/channels/CAM">
```

As so far I tried to wrap embed with object without significant result. Anyway code is:

```
    <object width="300" height="300" 
data="rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT/PSIA/streaming/channels/CAM_NUMBER" 
events="True"
 id="vlc_1" 
codebase="http://localhost:65211/axvlc.cab"
classid="clsid:4AD27CDD-8C2B-455E-8E2A-463E550B718F">
<param value="rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT/PSIA/streaming/channels/CAM_NUMBER" name="Src">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">
<param value="True" name="ShowDisplay">
<param value="False" name="AutoLoop">
<param value="True" name="AutoPlay">
<embed width="300" height="300" target="rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT/PSIA/streaming/channels/CAM_NUMBER" loop="no" autoplay="yes" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlc_1_embed" wmode="transparent">
</object>
```

The cab was prepared according: https://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX#Creating_an_VLC_ActiveX_Distribution

Solution sholud be based on plugin usage. Can't use re-streaming.

Device which produces stream is Hikvision DS-7208HVI-SH DVR.

How do I force IE to load this plugin? QuickTime would be ok but it doesn't open rtsp.

Answer (score 0):

First install Vlc Web Plugin (Mozilla and Firefox plugins) in the client. It installs automatically by installing Vlc Player.

Then in your code for IE activeX use this:

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
    id="vlc_1"
    codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab">
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://USER:PASSWORD@MY_IP:MY_PORT/PSIA/streaming/channels/CAM" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
</object>
```